# Gramblr internal server error 500

Tags: error

I have been editing my sketches in Photoshop, and saving them as jpgs, then uploading them to Instagram using Gramblr. This has been working great until today.

I am getting the error

```
"500 - Internal Server Error

Internal Server Error

Internal error information:
Configure failed. Unknown Server Error."
```

The only thing I have done differently that I can think, is I've started a new sketching subject, so I have switched file folders on my computer (Macbook Pro). I can't imagine switching folders would make a difference.

I have tried reopening the jpg in Photoshop, scaling it down to 1200 x 1200 pixels, save as jpg, and retrying to loading it with Gramblr. Same error.[image]

Comment: Actually this story IS useful. Not everyone who upload graphic files  know what internal server error  means but everyone can meet it. I suggest you insert the explaining comment to the text of your answer  as a quotation and accept your answer

Comment: @user287001 useful in general but off topic on GD.SE

Answer (score 1):

I swear I tried loading, reloading, rebooting, reloading again, resaving, and reloading some more before I posted the question. As soon as I posted the question, I tried loading one more time, and IT WORKED! I guess Gramblr has fixed itself, because I did nothing different.

Comment: A 500 internal server error means it's a problem on their side, so there would be nothing you could do to fix it besides contact them to let them know you were having a problem and what you did to recreate it. Apparently they fixed it in this case